# strange soft link ln command issue on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, symbolic-link

I want to create empty directory `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_5.jdk/Contents/Home/`, which points to the real directory `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/`, since some of the code is dependent on this specific version of JDK (1.8.0_5, but I only have 1.8.0_74) but ln command fails with the following error, any ideas what is wrong? Thanks.

BTW, I am using Mac OSX.

```
ls -l /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  102 Jan 20 16:32 Contents
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  102 Jan 25 16:16 jdk1.8.0_05.jdk
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  102 Jan 25 16:15 jdk1.8.0_25.jdk
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  102 Jan 25 16:15 jdk1.8.0_40.jdk
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  102 Jan 20 16:32 jdk1.8.0_72.jdk
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  102 Feb  5 15:25 jdk1.8.0_74.jdk
ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_5.jdk/Contents/Home/ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/
ln: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home//Home: File exists
```

Update, tried solution from Schlachter, but met with new issues,

```
ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
Contents        jdk1.7.0_51.jdk jdk1.8.0_25.jdk jdk1.8.0_72.jdk jdk1.8.0_77.jdk
jdk1.7.0_21.jdk jdk1.8.0_05.jdk jdk1.8.0_40.jdk jdk1.8.0_74.jdk

ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_5.jdk/Contents/
ln: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_5.jdk/Contents/: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `jdk1.8.0_5.jdk/Contents/Home` doesn't exist, you'd use:

`ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_5.jdk/Contents/`

The trailing slash on `Contents/` will put the `Home` shortcut inside of the `Contents` folder. There's no slash on the `Home` folder since it's the target of the link.

Edit: All the folders above where the link go need to exists. `mkdir` can create it/them for you, e.g. `mkdir -p /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_5.jdk/Contents`

Comment: Thanks D Schlachter for the reply, and vote up. I am wondering I should delete `jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home`? `jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home` is the directory with real content, and I want to create a directory name is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_5.jdk/Contents/Home ` which actually links to  `jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home`, which has real content.

Comment: I thought you needed it the other way around somehow  :)   I've edited my answer. If the empty `jdk1.8.0_5.jdk/Contents/Home` exists, you'll need to delete it. You just had the order of the directories backwards in your command (target goes first, location of the link second).

Comment: Thanks D Schlachter, vote up. Tried your solution, but still have issues. I have updated my answer with the command I executed and the output errors and appreciate if you could help to take a look. Thanks.

Comment: You just need to make the parent directories first: `mkdir -p /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_5.jdk/Contents`

Comment: Thanks D Schlachter for the patience to explain, vote up and mark reply as answer. :)